# Track Array changes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I wonder, if there is an easy way to implement a Ruby Array with behavior similar to `ActiveModel::Dirty`, so I can do:

```
array = [1,2]
array.changed? # => false
array << 5
array.changed? # => true
```

Until now, my only idea is to implement `TrackedArray < Array` or `TrackedArray < DelegateClass(Array)`, go through the public API of Array, call `define_method` for each method with exclamation mark and some others (like `keep_if`, `<<` and so on) and set a `@changed_marker = true`.

With that, I would get `changed? == true` for each array instance, which was changed once, but it would not go back to `changed? == false`, if one undoes the changed on the object. So it would not be fully compatible to `ActiveModel::Dirty`.

That seems like a big effort for a clumsy implementation...

Comment: You'll have to define changed. Does `array[1] += 1` count? Does `array.pop` count? What about `[{a: 1}]` and `array[0][:a] += 1`? There's a *lot* of methods that can modify an array.

Comment: When would `changed` be set to `false`? Only on initialize? Or is there some equivalent `save` method that then tells your object to now start tracking changes from that point?

Answer (score 1):

Naïve implementation (just out of curiosity):

```
class Hurray
  attr_accessor :dirty
  def initialize *args, &cb
    @array = Array.new *args, &cb
    @dirty = false
  end
  def method_missing m, *args, &cb
    @dup = @array.dup
     # maybe public_send, maybe whitelist methods
    @array.send(m, *args, &cb).tap do
      @dirty |= @dup != @array
    end
  end
end
```

One might make `attr_reader :dup` as well to have an access to last copy of the array before it was modified, e.g. for `undo`.